# I need help adding details to a span element

Tags: html

Step By step
1.create a DIV with CSS class of details and mdc-elevation--z3. This DIV should have 5 PARAGRAPH elements, each containing a SPAN with CSS class prop and another SPAN with CSS class of value

2.Using the SPAN elements so far created, your app will display the Age, Height, Weight, Gender, and Country of any given user. Let's call these the user properties!

3.For a given user property, e.g Age, locate a PARAGRAPH element and give the child SPAN with class prop an HTML attribute of data-age, then set its text value to Age :. The SPAN with class value should have an HTML attribute of data-age-value. The HTML attributes do not need to have a value.

4. Just like for Age, do same for all the user properties listed above, such that all pairs of SPAN elements are mapped to excatly one user property. Feel free to order them anyhow you like.

Here is My code

```
<div class = "details and mdc-elevation--z3">

<p>
    <span class="prop"> <a class ="data-age">Age :</a></span>
    <span class="value"><a class ="data-age-value"></a></span>
  </p>

  <p>
   <span class="prop"> <a class ="data-height">Height :</a></span>
    <span class="value"><a class ="data-height-value"></a></span>
  </p>

  <p>
   <span class="prop"> <a class ="data-weight">Weight :</a></span>
    <span class="value"><a class ="data-weight-value"></a></span>
  </p>

  <p>
   <span class="prop"> <a class ="data-gender">Gender :</a></span>
    <span class="value"><a class ="data-gender-value"></a></span>
  </p>

  <p>
  <span class="prop"> <a class ="data-country">Country :</a></span>
    <span class="value"><a class ="data-country-value"></a></span>
  </p>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow, please add relevant code to question, to get a better understanding of your question.

Comment: Please familiarize with [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We're happy to help you debug *your* code, but StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service. What have you tried? What are you having trouble with, specifically?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 2):

try this i believe it will help you

```
<div class = "details mdc-elevation--z3">

      <p>
        <span class = "prop" data-age>Age:</span>
        <span class = "value" data-age-value></span>
      </p>  
      <p>
        <span class = "prop" data-height>Height:</span>
        <span class = "value" data-height-value></span>
      </p> 
      <p>
        <span class = "prop" data-weight>Weight:</span>
        <span class = "value" data-weight-value></span>
      </p> 
      <p>
        <span class = "prop" data-gender>Gender:</span>
        <span class = "value" data-gender-value></span>
      </p> 
      <p>
        <span class = "prop" data-country>Country:</span>
        <span class = "value" data-country-value></span>
      </p> 

    </div>
```